# What happened when a router mount itself?

Tags: node.js, express

I made a minimal, reproducible example to demonstrate the problem.

package version: `"express": "^4.17.1"`

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const { Router } = express;
const router = Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('all services');
});
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
  res.send('get services by id');
});

router.use('/services', router);
app.use('/api/v1', router);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server started at http://localhost:3000'));
```

After starting the server:

```
server started at http://localhost:3000
```

I send HTTP request via `curl`:

```
☁  expressjs-research [master] ⚡  curl http://localhost:3000/api/v1/services
get services by id%                                                                      
☁  expressjs-research [master] ⚡  curl http://localhost:3000/api/v1/services/1
get services by id%                                                                      
☁  expressjs-research [master] ⚡  curl http://localhost:3000/api/v1           
all services%
```

It's weird. Here are my expectations:

- `/api/v1/services/1` => response `get services by id`
- `/api/v1/services` => response `all services`
- `/api/v1` => 404 not found

But obviously, the result is different from what I expected. I know I can solve it by creating and mounting a new sub router via the `Router()` class.

But I want to know when a router mounts itself, what happens.

Answer (score 0):

In the current implementation, the app's initial path is `/api/v1`.

```
.get('/');         // -> /
.get('/:id');      // -> /:id
.use('/services'); // -> /services
```

Here, a misunderstanding occurred because the path conflicted with `.get('/:id')` by `.use('services')`.

This does not add subpaths, it is **routing**.

---

1. when curling `api/v1/services`
2. the `router` receives `/services` from the app.
3. This works by mapping to `/:id`.

On the other hand

1. when curling `api/v1/services/1`
2. the `router` receives `services/1`
3. This of course does not map to `/:id`. But since it maps to `/services`, it routes `/1` to `router(self)`.
4. Eventually, after receiving `/1`, it is mapped to `/:id` and operates.

An interesting example is  `api/v1/services/services/services/services/services/1`.
As the above process is performed recursively, it is eventually mapped to `:id` and executed.

```sh
curl http://localhost:3000/api/v1/services/services/services/services/services/1
get services by id : 1
```

---

In order to work as you want, you can get the desired result by adding a path to `app.use` as shown below

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const { Router } = express;
const router = Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('all services');
});

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`get services by id : ${req.params.id}`);
});

app.use('/api/v1/services', router);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server started at http://localhost:3000'));
```

---

Or, you can try a `new router`.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const { Router } = express;
const router = Router();
const serviceRouter = Router();

serviceRouter.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('all services');
});

serviceRouter.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`get services by id : ${req.params.id}`);
});

router.use('/services', serviceRouter);

app.use('/api/v1', router);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server started at http://localhost:3000'));
```

---

results

```sh
curl http://localhost:3000/api/v1/services/1
get services by id : 1

curl http://localhost:3000/api/v1/services  
all services

curl http://localhost:3000/api/v1 
Cannot GET /api/v1
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the problem here is that you use the same router for both the `/api/v1` and the `/services` routes.

So if you request
`/api/v1` it will get passed to router because of `app.use('/api/v1', router);` and then take its `/route`, because its the only one that works.

If you request `/api/v1/services` it will also get passed to router because of `app.use('/api/v1', router);` and then take its `:id` route because its thinks the `/service` is an id and `router.get('/:id', (req, res)` comes before `router.use('/services', router);`

And the last one, `/api/v1/services/1` works perfectly fine, because it also gets passed to the router because of `app.use('/api/v1', router);` and there it takes the `router.use('/services', router);` route because nothing else works. Then it will go through router again and now it takes the `:id` route.

To solve the problem you can use different routers or you put the `router.use('/services', router);` to the top of your code, after `const router = Router();`